# grep: Not a recognized flag: o

Tags: grep, variable, aix

I am trying to extract the date and timestamps from my log file string (`$Data` in the below code) on AIX using a regex and loading it into a text file as below:

```
Data="Logs/2018-12-03/log.txt:3:2018-12-03 00:00:04,333 452621453 [blah blah blah"
echo "$data" | grep -o -n '[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]' >  timestamps.txt
```

I get the below error most probably due to the unix version in my host being too old and it doesn't recognize the `-o` option. Is there any alternative method in which I can get the functionality of `-o` done?

```
grep: Not a recognized flag: o
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
    [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L]  [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] [-e pattern_list...]
    -f pattern_file... [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] pattern_list [file...]
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: The command `uname -s` gives me 'AIX'

Comment: It's not that your Unix is "too old", it's that you are relying on non-standard functionality.

Comment: Is your `Data` variable a line from the output of `grep`? If it is, you can probably do whatever you are doing a fair bit more efficiently by running `perl` or `awk` over the original log files.  Parsing the output of `grep` is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that your regex wouldn't work even if `-o` was recognized by your `grep` implementation. You also need `-E` to enable extended regular expressions. Assuming you have `perl`, which you probably do, you can try:

```
$ Data="Logs/2018-12-03/log.txt:3:2018-12-03 00:00:04,333 452621453 [blah blah blah"
$ echo "$Data" | perl -lne '/[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]/ && print "$.:$&"'
1:2018-12-03 00:00
```

But do you really need to make your regex that complicated? Isn't this enough?

```
$ echo "$Data" | perl -lne '/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}/ && print "$.:$&"'
1:2018-12-03 00:00
```

Comment: Note also that the data in the `Data` variable is a line produced by `grep`. This makes me think that the user is first running a grep of some kind to get the lines they want, and then iterating in a shell loop over these lines.  This is quite an suboptimal approach to log file parsing.